# is there any way to create electric field around two similarly charged plates?

Tags: electrostatics, capacitance

Can an electric field exist around two similarly charged plates, like if we consider to put small paper pallets around it so that it can attract paper pallets without generating repulsion ?

Comment: Hint: Think of a parallel plate capacitor. What happens then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In reference to what you are asking, the two similarly charged plates would repel each other. Now if the two plates are kept in an electric field then the two cases can exist:
If the outside electric field is opposing the electric field between two plates and is larger than the field between between two plates than the paper bits would be attract ed towards the plate.
If outside electric field is smaller than the electric field between the two plates then the two plates would not attract the paper.